# How to publish on private pub server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dart, dart-pub

I'm setting up a private pub server in the docker container ([here](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/pub_server_private))
I start the server with `./start.sh` and I can see the packages thanks to the UI here: http://0.0.0.0:30000
Now that my server is ready I want to publish a package inside with: `pub publish --server http://0.0.0.0:8080`
from the command line everything seems correct `my_core 0.0.1 uploaded successfully but when I check the logs on the server with`./log.sh`
I saw that there are some error logs:
(something related to the address 0.0.0.0:30000)
Any advices ?
Cheers

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 1887, in ExecuteTask
    '0.1.0.2')
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 620, in add_request
    headers_dict['Host'], urlparse.urlsplit(relative_url).path)
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 690, in _resolve_target
    raise request_info.ModuleDoesNotExistError(hostname)
ModuleDoesNotExistError: 0.0.0.0:30000
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:24,645 taskqueue_stub.py:1962] An error occured while sending the task "task2" (Url: "/_ah/queue/deferred") in queue "default". Treating as a task error.
WARNING  2015-02-03 22:37:24,646 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
INFO     2015-02-03 22:37:24,653 module.py:718] default: "GET /api/packages/versions/2c67df44-6af2-4a52-a632-6c4d35147146/create HTTP/1.1" 200 68
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:24,746 taskqueue_stub.py:1889] Failed to dispatch task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 1887, in ExecuteTask
    '0.1.0.2')
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 620, in add_request
    headers_dict['Host'], urlparse.urlsplit(relative_url).path)
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 690, in _resolve_target
    raise request_info.ModuleDoesNotExistError(hostname)
ModuleDoesNotExistError: 0.0.0.0:30000
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:24,746 taskqueue_stub.py:1962] An error occured while sending the task "task2" (Url: "/_ah/queue/deferred") in queue "default". Treating as a task error.
WARNING  2015-02-03 22:37:24,747 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.200 seconds
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:24,947 taskqueue_stub.py:1889] Failed to dispatch task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 1887, in ExecuteTask
    '0.1.0.2')
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 620, in add_request
    headers_dict['Host'], urlparse.urlsplit(relative_url).path)
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 690, in _resolve_target
    raise request_info.ModuleDoesNotExistError(hostname)
ModuleDoesNotExistError: 0.0.0.0:30000
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:24,948 taskqueue_stub.py:1962] An error occured while sending the task "task2" (Url: "/_ah/queue/deferred") in queue "default". Treating as a task error.
WARNING  2015-02-03 22:37:24,948 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.400 seconds
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:25,349 taskqueue_stub.py:1889] Failed to dispatch task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 1887, in ExecuteTask
    '0.1.0.2')
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 620, in add_request
    headers_dict['Host'], urlparse.urlsplit(relative_url).path)
  File "/home/app/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 690, in _resolve_target
    raise request_info.ModuleDoesNotExistError(hostname)
ModuleDoesNotExistError: 0.0.0.0:30000
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:25,349 taskqueue_stub.py:1962] An error occured while sending the task "task2" (Url: "/_ah/queue/deferred") in queue "default". Treating as a task error.
WARNING  2015-02-03 22:37:25,349 taskqueue_stub.py:1977] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.800 seconds
ERROR    2015-02-03 22:37:26,150 taskqueue_stub.py:1889] Failed to dispatch task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/google_ap`